# FrameTicks given through Show does not work with LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting

This is similar to the closed topic: [Frame ticks for a Log Log plot [closed]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/frame-ticks-for-a-log-log-plot). Let me reuse (rm -rf)'s example here.

FrameTicks given through Show does not appear if used with LogLogPlot:

```
Show[
  LogLogPlot[x^2 + x^3, {x, 1, 100}, Frame -> True],
  FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {{10, 30, 75}, None}}
]
```

This works though:

```
Show[
  LogLogPlot[x^2 + x^3, {x, 1, 100}, Frame -> True],
  FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {{N@Log@#, #}& /@ {10, 30, 75}, None}}
]
```

Is this a bug or an expected behaviour?

Comment: Great that your question gives a copiable solution to my problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a difference in how the ticks are processed. When given as part of LogLogPlot, they are scaled before they are displayed. You can see this if you extract them from the `Graphics` object:

```
LogLogPlot[x^2 + x^3, {x, 1, 100}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {{10, 30, 75}, None}}] /.
 Graphics[_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :> (FrameTicks /. Flatten@{opts})[[2]]
```

which returns

```
{{{2.30259, 10}, {3.4012, 30}, {4.31749, 75}}, None}
```

which is the same as

```
{{N@Log[#], #} & /@ {10, 30, 75}, None}
```

Notice that each tick is specified as `{value, label}`, and it is needed to place the ticks correctly while labeling them correctly.  Now, `Show` does not do the same processing because it knows nothing about *how* the plot was put together; all it knows about is the `Graphics` object, itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand `Show` more!